# Socket Python Select and Multiprocessing

Tags: python, sockets, select, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I want some explanation about a something to do with sockets...
Suppose I create a Socket (Server and Client) for chatting, every client of this socket will receive data from the server and send data to the server, which will send data to all the clients, simultaneously. How can the server accept all the connections simultaneously?
I know that with the module "socket" there are 3 method:

1. create more threads with module "threading" but it isn't the best way
2. create more processes with module multiprocessing
3. use the module select

What is the best way?
what is the difference between using select and using multiprocessing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just some generalities based on my very limited experience with socket programming.

They are two completely different ways of handling IO.

select is often used to achieve non blocking IO, usually in a single thread.  Tornado is a mature example of a framework around this.
http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/,  Tornado uses select (or equivalent internally)

Using select has the advantage of not having to worry about multithreaded/process programming, using os to notify of file descriptor changes allows a single thread to handle many hundreds or thousands or tens of thousands of open sockets.

Threading is a great way of dealing with io as well.   Because the thread will not be cpu bound it is often acceptable and performant to spawn many io bound threads.  Since the threads will be spending most of their time waiting on IO there *shouldn't be much overhead.

I would def look at tornado, as it has a chat example that is trivial to create

There are many many examples, blogs and tutorials of chat servers, performant python webservers and socket programming in python on google